# Error creating Pdf with Gehtsoft Pdf Builder

Tags: pdf, creation

I am creating a Pdf with a barcode in the header...

```
private void BuildHeader(RepeatingAreaBuilder builder)
        {
            var tableBuilder = builder.AddTable();
            tableBuilder
                .SetWidth(XUnit.FromPercent(100))
                .SetBorder(Stroke.None)
                .AddColumnPercentToTable("", 30)
                .AddColumnPercentToTable("", 50)
                .AddColumnToTable("", 20);

            var rowBuilder = tableBuilder.AddRow();
            var cellBuilder = rowBuilder.AddCell()
                .SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.Center)
                .SetPadding(17, 0, 0, 0);
            cellBuilder.AddParagraph("APP/PipeKing").SetFont(FNT20B);

            cellBuilder = rowBuilder.AddCell();
            cellBuilder.AddParagraph(_mixer.MixPlantName + " Mixing Sheet").SetFont(FNT20B);

            cellBuilder = rowBuilder.AddCell();
            cellBuilder.AddParagraph()
                .AddBarcodeToParagraph("12345678", BarcodeType.EAN_8);

        }
```

this fails at

```
    **cellBuilder.AddParagraph()
                .AddBarcodeToParagraph("12345678", BarcodeType.EAN_8);**
```

with the following error message:

Gehtsoft.PDFFlow.Models.Exceptions.NotEnoughSpaceException: 'The inline image is larger than the available space on the page. Width: 81, Height: 65.75'

How do I get the barcode to display?

I have tried numerous `.FromHeight` and `.FromWidth` scenarios to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```html
byte[] _barcode;

_barcode = BarcodesMaker.GetBarcode("01234501",
                BarcodeType.EAN_8,
                System.Drawing.Color.Black,
                System.Drawing.Color.White,
                true,
                MeasureBarcodeUnit.FromPixel(0));
                
cellBuilder = rowBuilder.AddCell();
cellBuilder.AddImage(_barcode, 100f, 50, ScalingMode.None);
```